# How to get the textarea to be same height as row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with my textarea. I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WZKrP/15/).

When you open fiddle, simply click on the "Add Question" button and yo will see a row appended underneath.

You will be able to see that the textarea's height does not fit the whole row. My question is that how can I get the textarea's height to fit the whole row? The height of a row can be any size, there is no fixed size.

Below is css which controls textarea(s) in appended row and the row itself:

```
.question textarea {
    min-width:98%;
    max-width:98%;
    resize:none;
    height:auto;
    font-size:100%;
}

.question { 
    min-width:28%;
    max-width:28%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Please test your code in fiddle before posting your answer :)

Comment: without looking at the jsfiddle, when I only look to your posted css, I see a width for the text area of 98%. How should that ever fill the row completely?

Comment: remove jsfiddle tag becuase *** using jsFiddle, a web application allowing users to create and execute code written in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Do not use this tag to indicate that your question contains a jsFiddle example.*** i dont have permission to re-tag

Comment: @SvenBieder It's because if the width is 100%, on some browsers the textare looks like its overlapping the row so that's why I put it at 98%

Comment: to prevent the the addition of the border width to the overall width, you can set the box-sizing to border-box, then the border is included in the overall width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `textarea's` `height` to `100%`

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZKrP/16/)**

Comment: Strange when I tried this before it didn't work but now it works. Must of not refreshed the page properly when I tried it previously

Comment: @user1723760 If you found it useful , do upvote it as well.Thanks.